# Select multiple items in dropdown having chekboxes

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a dropdown menu with checkboxes in it. I can select multiple items by clicking on the checkboxes. But could not select by clicking on item name in the dropdown box. Now, when I click on name instead of checkbox, the cursor goes to top of the webpage and nothing got selected in the dropdown menu. Is there any way that I can click on multiple dropdown menu items and they got selected? 
My code is as follows :

```
<div id="parents"  style="display:block">   
     <div class="col-sm-5">
      <div class="dropdown test">
         &nbsp;<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" name="single[]" id="single">Select Event Singles
           <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
                <?php

     $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "passwd", "db_name") or die("could not connect to database") . "<br>";
                                    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT EventID,Event_Name FROM events where EventID IN (2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,16,17,18,20)");
                                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                        // output data of each row
                                        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                                            echo "<li><a href='#' class='test'><input type='checkbox' name='frames[]' value='".$row['EventID']."' >" . $row["Event_Name"] . "</input></a></li>";
                                        }


                                    }
                                    $mysqli->close();
                                    ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: We can't understand your question. You want to select multiple options right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <div id="parents"  style="display:block">   
<div class="col-sm-5">
    <div class="dropdown test">
        &nbsp;<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" name="single[]" id="single">Select Event Singles
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
        <?php
            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "passwd", "db_name") or die("could not connect to database") . "<br>";
            $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT EventID,Event_Name FROM events where EventID IN (2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,16,17,18,20)");
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                    echo "<li><input type='checkbox' name='frames[]' value='".$row['EventID']."' id='checkbox_".$row['EventID']."'></input><label for='checkbox_".$row['EventID']."'>" . $row["Event_Name"] . "</label></li>";
                }


            }
            $mysqli->close();
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can try this.

You can assign ID to each checkbox.

Add label for each checkbox text.

Add "for" attribute to each label and assign ID of respective checkboxes.

Comment: thank you, its working but the problem is when i select one item then cursor goes to top of the page. Is there any way that the cursor will remain on the same dropdown menu to select multiple items ?

Comment: @AtulPatil You used <a> tag. Remove it and try. it'll fix your problem

Comment: @AtulPatil I've updated my code please try with it. And also do up vote.

Comment: @AtulPatil If you need to keep the `<a> tag` you can assign the same class to all the `<a> tags` and add this to your jQuery: $('.yourClass').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }); `e.preventDefault();` removes the default behavior of a element. In this case, it will remove the jump to top.

Comment: @JuanJ Seems no reason to use. why we render extra dom element if it's not necessary.

Comment: Agree with @Rajesh

Comment: @Rajesh You are 100% correct on that one. I did mention `if` he needs to keep it, I did not state that he should use it.

Comment: @JuanJ Yes you are right, but we should suggest optimize code which get execute/Render fast.